# Align Content on Line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using jQuery marquee plugin to achieve marquee effect.
Now the problem is i want to achieve this kind of alignment .

[image]

And now look at my solution.
I want that "Treading" button on the same line of marquee text as the above image.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance for you efforts.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    allowCss3Support: true,
    easing: 'linear',
    delayBeforeStart: 1000,
    direction: 'left',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    speed: 18000,
    gap: 20
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <section>
      <p class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Trending
        <div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>
      </p>
   </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: how about reducing the width to say `width: 92%;` for `.marquee`?

Comment: Maybe you should use `span` instead of `div` for `<div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With flexbox (not working in old browsers):

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    allowCss3Support: true,
    easing: 'linear',
    delayBeforeStart: 1000,
    direction: 'left',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    speed: 1000,
    gap: 20
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ddd;
}
.wrapper-markee{
  display: flex; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <section class="wrapper-markee">
      <p class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Trending
        <div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>
      </p>
   </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I also changed speed, change it back if you want to copy

Comment: Great.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply float the elements to left and set the width of marquee to screen length minus button length using css `calc`

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    allowCss3Support: true,
    easing: 'linear',
    delayBeforeStart: 1000,
    direction: 'left',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    speed: 18000,
    gap: 20
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 69px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}
.btn {
  float: left;
  width: 69px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Trending </span>
    <div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>

  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> using floats you can achieve wht exactly u want

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.marquee').marquee({
    allowCss3Support: true,
    easing: 'linear',
    delayBeforeStart: 1000,
    direction: 'left',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    speed: 18000,
    gap: 20
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 69px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float: left;"> Trending </span>
    <div class="marquee" style=" float: left;">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.9/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
</body>
```